# Optimizing sales in excel/google sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets, optimize, solver

I have a table that looks like that:

| investment | p1 | p2 | p3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 100 | 50 | 80 |
| 2000 | 200 | 60 | 95 |
| 3000 | 300 | 70 | 110 |
| 4000 | 400 | 80 | 125 |
| 5000 | 500 | 90 | 140 |
| 6000 | 600 | 100 | 155 |
| 7000 | 700 | 110 | 170 |
| 8000 | 800 | 120 | 185 |
| 9000 | 900 | 130 | 200 |
| 10000 | 1000 | 140 | 215 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 15000 | 1500 | 190 | 290 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 20000 | 2000 | 240 | 365 |

The p1,p2,p3 are different platforms that I can advertise on. 
The most left column is how much I will invest in a platform, the values are the total sales that I will get from a platform if I will invest the money on the most lest column. 
For example, if I'm investing 1000 in p1 I will get 100 sales. 
My problem is given a budget of 20000, how should I split it between the platforms such that I will have the maximum sales. 
For example, 15000 on p1 + 5000 on p2 + 5000 on p3 will give me 1500 + 90 + 140 = 1730 sales.
I tried to think how can I do it in google sheets (or excel), is it possible to solve this optimization only with formulas? Or maybe I should use solver somehow, I'm pretty new to this so I'm kind of stuck. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: For the sample data invest everything in P1!  You cant beat the 2000 sales any other way.

Comment: All on P1, which gives you 2000.  No need for solver!

Comment: **15000 on p1 + 5000 on p2 + 5000 on p3**.  That's 25,000 investment.